# User-Access return value issue

Tags: 7, users

I'm executing the following code in hook_init:

```
function my_module_init(){
    global $user;

    $apprenticeship = user_access('prevent publishing apprenticeship job', $user);
    drupal_set_message("CHECKING permission[prevent publishing apprenticeship job]: " . $apprenticeship);
    $content = user_access('access content', $user);
    drupal_set_message("CHECKING permission[access content]: " . $content);
}
```

I am logged in as USER#1 and the *prevent publishing apprenticeship job* permission is **NOT** set for user#1.

However, each time my code executes `user_access('prevent publishing apprenticeship job', $user)` returns 1 i:e true.

As I said, that permission is not set for for the administrator role.

Can anyone help and point out what I'm missing or doing wrong?

PS:

The `access content` also returns 1 but that is set for the administrator role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user #1 is special, in Drupal. It will always have all permissions, even the ones not explicitly set for the administrator role.

See [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7.x) source code.

```
  // User #1 has all privileges:
  if ($account->uid == 1) {
    return TRUE;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks TytooF. I suspected! User#1 or not user_access should probably be true to the values set on the permissions page.